# Listing details of USB drives using python and udisk2

Tags: python, dbus

I have developed an application which uses udisks version 1 to find and list details of connected USB drives. The details include device (/dev/sdb1...etc), mount point, and free space. However, I found that modern distros has udisks2 installed by default. Here is the little code found on the other SO thread:-

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
import dbus
bus = dbus.SystemBus()
ud_manager_obj = bus.get_object('org.freedesktop.UDisks2', '/org/freedesktop/UDisks2')
om = dbus.Interface(ud_manager_obj, 'org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager')
for k,v in om.GetManagedObjects().iteritems():
  drive_info = v.get('org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Drive', {})
  if drive_info.get('ConnectionBus') == 'usb' and drive_info.get('Removable'):
    if drive_info['MediaRemovable']:
      print("Device Path: %s" % k)
```

It produces:-

`[sundar@arch ~]$ ./udisk2.py 
Device Path: /org/freedesktop/UDisks2/drives/JetFlash_Transcend_8GB_GLFK4LYSFG3HZZ48`

The above result is fine but how can I connect `org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Block` and get properties of the devices?

http://udisks.freedesktop.org/docs/latest/gdbus-org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Block.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After lot of hit and trial, I could get what I wanted. Just posting it so that some one can benefit in the future. Here is the code:-

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
# coding: utf-8
import dbus


def get_usb():
    devices = []
    bus = dbus.SystemBus()
    ud_manager_obj = bus.get_object('org.freedesktop.UDisks2', '/org/freedesktop/UDisks2')
    om = dbus.Interface(ud_manager_obj, 'org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager')
    try:
        for k,v in om.GetManagedObjects().iteritems():
            drive_info = v.get('org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Block', {})
            if drive_info.get('IdUsage') == "filesystem" and not drive_info.get('HintSystem') and not drive_info.get('ReadOnly'):
                device = drive_info.get('Device')
                device = bytearray(device).replace(b'\x00', b'').decode('utf-8')
                devices.append(device)
    except:
        print "No device found..."
    return devices



def usb_details(device):
    bus = dbus.SystemBus()
    bd = bus.get_object('org.freedesktop.UDisks2', '/org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices%s'%device[4:])
    try:
        device = bd.Get('org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Block', 'Device', dbus_interface='org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties')
        device = bytearray(device).replace(b'\x00', b'').decode('utf-8')
        print "printing " + device
        label = bd.Get('org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Block', 'IdLabel', dbus_interface='org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties')
        print 'Name od partition is %s'%label
        uuid = bd.Get('org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Block', 'IdUUID', dbus_interface='org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties')
        print 'UUID is %s'%uuid
        size = bd.Get('org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Block', 'Size', dbus_interface='org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties')
        print 'Size is %s'%uuid
        file_system =  bd.Get('org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Block', 'IdType', dbus_interface='org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties')
        print 'Filesystem is %s'%file_system
    except:
        print "Error detecting USB details..."
```

The complete block device properties can be found here http://udisks.freedesktop.org/docs/latest/gdbus-org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Block.html

Comment: In case anybody wonders: For Python3 you have to change the following: missing () at `print`, replace `iteritems()` with `items()`.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**
Note that the `Block` object does not have `ConnectionBus` or `Removable` properties. You will have to change the code to remove references to `Drive` object properties for the code to work. 
**/Edit**

If you want to connect to `Block`, not `Drive`, then instead of

```
drive_info = v.get('org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Drive', {})
```

try

```
drive_info = v.get('org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Block', {})
```

Then you can iterate through `drive_info` and output it's properties.  For example, to get the `Id` property, you could:

```
print("Id: %s" % drive_info['Id'])
```

I'm sure that there is a nice pythonic way to iterate through all the property key/value pairs and display the values, but I'll leave that to you.  Key being `'Id'` and value being the string stored in `drive_info['Id']`.  Good luck

Comment: Your answer is almost close. I have a little problem again. I would like to get details like, mount point, uuid, label, type of the disk device file (/dev/sdb1) and so on. When i change `drive_info` in to filesystem and so on, it simply returns None.  Little explanation will be very useful.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by change `drive_info` to filesystem. You should be able to get any property listed in the properties section of the Web page that you linked at the end of your question by the method I described. There is a property called `IdUUID` so I would imagine that `drive_info['IdUUID']` would access that value. If you're looking for properties that are not described in the `Block` object, I'm not sure how to help (unless they are in the `Drive` object)