# Is it possible to get the mountpoint of a pendrive knowing its serialnumber using python?

Tags: python, linux, windows, serial-number, usb-drive

I have 2 PC's(a Linux and a Windows) connected to a local network which is on a different floor. People on that floor connect their USB Pen-drives to either one of the PC and I am suppose to copy different specific set of files to different people.

Previously,

- what i did was so hard (get to the floor and do it manually)
- Later i wrote a python program that copies specific set of file to
  specific person on my decision through `ssh`. (ie,. I log in to the
  specific machine through `ssh`, ask users *(over a phone call)* one by one to insert their
  pen-drive and then i execute the python program which accepted an
  argument. This argument is nothing but a name whom i wanted to copy,
  and by receiving the argument the program  decides which files to be
  copied to the pen-drive).
  Still the process is bit tedious,..
  Because only one pen-drive could connected and i had to do this repeatedly for every user.

So to reduce the total time consumed, i connected USB hubs on both the systems to make multiple insert of pen-drive's in a given time. And here comes the problem, decide which device belonged to whom.

**Question :** Is it possible to find the mount point of a pen-drive from the `SerialNumber` using python ? (it would be great if its python, since the main program is written in python)

The reason i am considering `SerialNumber` over,

- `UUID` - It changes when the device is formatted
- `Vendor`, `ProdID` and `Manufacturer` - Not sure that if they will be
  different. (ie,. what if its from the same manufacturer and a same
  model)

I tried `wmi` for windows.. and got this code from SO,(Sorry i don't have the link. Took it long back)

```
import win32com.client

wmi = win32com.client.GetObject ("winmgmts:")
for usb in wmi.InstancesOf ("Win32_USBHub"):
    print usb.DeviceID
```

the output i get is

```
USB\VID_5986&PID_0292\6&4817B6D&0&6
USB\VID_8087&PID_0024\5&55D1EEC&0&1
USB\VID_8087&PID_0024\5&88B8ABA&0&1
USB\ROOT_HUB20\4&11F77F7&0
USB\ROOT_HUB20\4&62BF53D&0
USB\VID_03F0&PID_3307\JN0W5LAB0ZHQ5VK8
```

its  the similar case in linux, all i able to get is serialnumber, using `usb-devices`. But unable to get its corresponding mount-point

Any Ideas please...

Comment: See [this for D-Bus solution on recent Linuxen](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5081937/918959)

Comment: Sorry, the udisks has been deprecated for long now, try [this approach instead](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23244245/918959)

Comment: Notice, that with udev it is very easy to run commands on linux that run automatically when a usb device is attached mounted; you could mount each and every device to a different path or even automatically execute the copy command; no python nor polling needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do that on **Linux** you will need to parse `/proc/mounts` to determine mapping of device names to mountpoints, i.e. `/dev/sdc2` -> `/var/run/media/myaut/hyperx`.

The trick is to find out what device name has required serial number. Easiest approach to do so is to use `udev` - it uses serial when generates symlinks in `/dev/disk/by-id`:

```
/dev/disk/by-id/usb-Generic_Flash_Disk_12345678-0:0 -> ../../sdd
```

But we didn't seek for easiest solutions, are we? The trick is that `udev` rules may be altered, and `sysfs` (which come from kernel) is more reliable. I implemented a script that does that:

```
import os
import sys
import glob

SYS_USB_DEVICES = '/sys/bus/usb/devices'
SYS_BLOCK_DEVICES = '/sys/class/block'

try:
    serial = sys.argv[1]
except IndexError:
    print >> sys.stderr, "Usage: findflash.py SERIAL"
    sys.exit(1)

# PASS 1 Find USB node with corresponding to serial

for usbid in os.listdir(SYS_USB_DEVICES):
    usbserpath = os.path.join(SYS_USB_DEVICES, usbid, 'serial')    
    if not os.path.exists(usbserpath):
        continue    
    with open(usbserpath) as f:
        usb_serial = f.read().strip()

    if serial == usb_serial:
        # Found it!
        break
else:
    print >> sys.stderr, "Cannot find usb device with serial {0}".format(serial)
    sys.exit(1)

# Find SCSI ids corresponding to this device
# I didn't check SYSFS documentation, but tested it on openSUSE 13.1
# The form of path is:
#   <SUBDEVICE>/host<SCSI_HOST_ID>/target<SCSI_TARGET_ID>/<CTRL><CHANNEL>:<TGT>:<LUN>
# We need only basename

devs = glob.glob(os.path.join(SYS_USB_DEVICES, usbid, 
                            '*/host*/target*/*:*:*:*'))

devs = map(os.path.basename, devs)

# PASS 2 - find mountpoints for devices with SCSI ids we discover earlier

# Parse mountpoint formatted as "/dev/... /path/to/mntpt ..." 
def parse_mntpt(line):
    dev, mntpt, _ = line.split(None, 2)
    dev = os.path.basename(dev)
    return dev, mntpt

mntpts = {}
with open('/proc/mounts') as f:
    mntpts = dict(map(parse_mntpt, f.readlines()))

# List of ('scsi id', 'dev name', 'mnt pt (if exists)')
devlist = []

def create_dev(scsiid, devname):
    global mntpts
    devlist.append((scsiid, devname, mntpts.get(devname)))

for devname in os.listdir(SYS_BLOCK_DEVICES):
    devpath = os.path.join(SYS_BLOCK_DEVICES, devname)
    devlink = os.path.join(devpath, 'device')

    # Node is "virtual", i.e. partition, ignore it
    if not os.path.islink(devlink):
        continue

    scsiid = os.path.basename(os.readlink(devlink))    
    if scsiid not in devs:
        continue

    create_dev(scsiid, devname)

    # Find partition names
    parts = glob.glob(os.path.join(devpath, '*/partition'))

    for partpath in parts:
        partname = os.path.basename(os.path.dirname(partpath))
        create_dev(scsiid, partname)

# END - print results
fmtstr = '{0:8} {1:5} {2}'
print fmtstr.format('SCSI ID', 'DEV', 'MOUNT POINT')
for scsiid, devname, mntpt in devlist:
    print fmtstr.format(scsiid, devname, mntpt)
```

Here is example output:

```
$ python findflash.py 12345678
SCSI ID  DEV   MOUNT POINT
8:0:0:0  sdd   None
8:0:0:0  sdd1  /var/run/media/myaut/Debian\040wheezy\04020140723-17:30
8:0:0:0  sdd2  None
8:0:0:0  sdd5  None
8:0:0:1  sr0   None
```

I can't say that on **Windows** that would be easy. I have a code (in C/WinAPI) that able to collect all disk devices from system, but it's logic is far away from filesystems representation, so I still didn't find a solution for that.

Complexity of Windows come from that:

- There is set of functions like SetupDi* that allow you enumerate disk devices. Their names are come in PnP style, unrelated to volume names.
- There is DOS-style API (i.e. working on level of A: and C:)
- There is WinNT-style API that knows about volumes, and probably, mountpoints.

Of course linking that three layers is not obvious (there is approach to match partitions by their size/offset, but that is crazy). I'm still scared to implement it in my library :(

Comment: ,.. Thanks a lot, this worked awesome. And your comments did explained well about the process, Thanks for your detailed explanation,..

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `lsblk` for linux if you don't mind running an external process.
Mind that a disk has a serial number while a partition, which is mounted, does not.

```py
p_handler = subprocess.run(
    ['lsblk', '-J', '-o', 'PATH,SERIAL,MOUNTPOINT'],
    check=True,
    capture_output=True)
json_output = json.loads(p_handler.stdout.decode("utf-8"))
# (serial, device_path, mount_point)
drives = [(dev['serial'], dev['path'], dev['mountpoint'])
          for dev in json_output['blockdevices']]
print(drives)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: please add exception support, because you newer know, `lsblk` command is available on the system.